# Converting if else statement to java statement using ternary operator

Tags: java, algorithm, ternary

Is it possible to convert the below java code using ternary operator:

```
if (x > 0) {
    a = 100;
    b = 100;
} else {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
}
```

Comment: you can do it with two ternary operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
a = b = x > 0 ? 100 : 1;
```

but only because you assign the same value to `a` and `b`.

In the general case, you'd need a separate ternary conditional operator for each variable you wish to assign to:

```
a = x > 0 ? 100 : 1;
b = x > 0 ? 100 : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this with one ternary expression:

```
a = x > 0 ? 100 : 1;
b = a;
```

This works because the assignment logic for both `a` and `b` happens to be the same.  If that were not the case, we would need two separate ternary expressions:

```
a = x > 0 ? 100 : 1;
b = x > 0 ? 100 : 1;
```